# PMTiles raster for Leaflet and opacity slider

Tags: leaflet, slider

I can't find a working slider in Leaflet with PMTiles rasters.
With the PMTiles vector there are no problems.
I searched other requests and found nothing.
I think it's due to PMTiles not loading as a layer.

Do you have any suggestions?